# How to populate a database through seed method using foreign keys and creating a relationship between tables in .NET C# EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-binding

My seed method contains as follows:

```
        var professors = new List<Professor>
        {
            new Professor
            {
                Name = "Arturo Anand",
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("09-08-2015")
            }
        };

        professors.ForEach(prof => context.Professors.AddOrUpdate(prof));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var presentations = new List<Presentation>
        {
            new Presentation
            {
                PresentationTitle = "Test",
                PresentationTime = DateTime.Parse("09-09-2015"),
                Level = Level.Advanced,
            }
        };

        presentations.ForEach(pres => context.Presentations.AddOrUpdate(pres));
        context.SaveChanges();
```

This is the relationship between the 2 classes:
Presentation class:

```
    public class Presentation
{
    public int PresentationId { get; set; }
    public string PresentationTitle { get; set; }
    public DateTime PresentationTime { get; set; }
    public Level? Level { get; set; }
    public virtual Professor Professor { get; set; }
}
```

Professor class:

```
  public class Professor
{
    public int ProfessorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Presentation> Presentations { get; set; }
}
```

I don't really know how I should populate the db from the seed method in order to bind data to a form from both tables to create CRUD operations on them.

EDIT:
Professor model:

```
    public class Professor
{
    public int ProfessorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Presentation> Presentations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: what is Level? does that code compile I am trying to run your code less the foreach's and the save and I get errors.. also why is it hard for you to bind the data that you are getting in your List<T> of class Professor and Presentation..?

Comment: Level is just an enum, my concern is that if I populate with data the tables, the presentation table will not have any professor id bound to it.

Comment: Sorry if it's a stupid question..I am new at this and I didn't found anything about populating tables through seed method based on foreign keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is a relatioship between `Professors` and `Presentation` you can assign the presentation directly to the Professor object EF will fill the FK for you. Try this

```
protected override void Seed(yourDbContext context)
{

       var professors = new List<Professor>
       {
         new Professor
         {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Arturo Anand",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("09-08-2015"),
            Presentations = new List<Presentation>
              {
                 new Presentation
                 {
                 PresentationTitle = "Test",
                 PresentationTime = DateTime.Parse("09-09-2015"),
                 Level = Level.Advanced,
                 }
              }
         }
     };
  //make sure to specify a key for the AddOrUpdate Method to ensure 
  //that you don’t create duplicates when you seed data during development.
   professors.ForEach(prof => context.Professors.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id, prof));
}
```

also you don't need to call `SaveChanges`. Running the command `Update-Database`        will execute the seed method.

Comment: It complains that my Professor model does not contain Presentation.

Comment: it should be Presentations because is the name of your property, check my answer i edited the line.

Comment: Hi @user3399858 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Not exactly..currently only Professor table is filled with data, I am trying to solve this, and after that I will post the answer here&accept your answer. The code you post seems to be fine, I guess the problem is somewhere on my side.

Comment: After a rebuild and update-database again, the db is populated with data. Thanks again!